# C++. Записать в бинарный файл объекты класса. Затем прочитать их из файла и вывести на экран

Tags: c++

Компилятор выдает ошибку.
Не могу понять, что именно вызывает эту ошибку. 
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, Заранее спасибо!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Product
{
public:
    unsigned int Art;
    string Name;
    short int Measure;
    double Amount;
    Product(unsigned int C_Art, string C_Name, short int C_Measure, double C_Amount)
    {
        Art = C_Art;
        Name = C_Name;
        Measure = C_Measure;
        Amount = C_Amount;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        cout << Art << "  " << Name << "  " << Measure << "  " << Amount << endl;
    }
};

// Инициализация
void Function_Initial()
{
    Product Bread(12, "Bread", 2, 5);
    Product Cookies(23, "Cookies", 3, 16);
    Product Meat(6, "Meat", 1, 10);
    Product Sugar(32, "Sugar", 1, 20);
    Product Candies(12, "Candies", 3, 7);
    Product Melon(12, "Melon", 2, 2);
    ofstream Bin_Out("Bin.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Bread, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Cookies, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Meat, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Sugar, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Candies, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.write((char*)&Melon, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_Out.close();
}

// Вывод
void Function_Print()
{
    Product Bread(0, "", 0, 0);
    Product Cookies(0, "", 0, 0);
    Product Meat(0, "", 0, 0);
    Product Sugar(0, "", 0, 0);
    Product Candies(0, "", 0, 0);
    Product Melon(0, "", 0, 0);
    ifstream Bin_In("Bin.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Bread, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Cookies, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Meat, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Sugar, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Candies, sizeof(Product));
    Bin_In.read((char*)&Melon, sizeof(Product));
    Bread.Print();
    Cookies.Print();
    Meat.Print();
    Sugar.Print();
    Candies.Print();
    Melon.Print();
    Bin_In.close();
}
int main()
{
    Function_Initial();
    Function_Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка, которую выдает компилятор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В класса `Product` имеется поле типа `std::string`. Этот класс хранит внутри себя несколько указателей. Поэтому его **не в коем случае нельзя переносить побайтово**!

Comment: Спасибо большое) Заменил на массив символов, все заработало!